# A "New" Special Point in a Triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I was playing with the software Geometry Expressions and I was exploring generalizations of special points in triangles (centroid, orthocenters, etc.) when I stumbled upon this construction.

[image]

J is always located at the intersection of the three lines but can either be inside or outside the triangle depending upon its shape.
If one positions A",B",C" at the critical distance from C,B, A, one can construct a second point J".

[image]

J and J'on the same figure:

[image]

Different triangles, with J inside or outside:
[image]

[image]

**Proof:**

The way I constructed the point J:
Position A',B',C' such that:
$$ \overrightarrow{CA'} =k \overrightarrow{CA} $$
$$ \overrightarrow{BB'} =k \overrightarrow{BC} $$
$$ \overrightarrow{AC'} =k \overrightarrow{AB} $$

Define J:
$$ \overrightarrow{BC'}  .  \overrightarrow{C'J} =0 $$
$$ \overrightarrow{AA'}  .  \overrightarrow{A'J} =0 $$
$$  \overrightarrow{BB'}  .  \overrightarrow{B'J} =0 $$

Solve for k and find: $$ k= \frac{ a^{2} +b^{2}+c^{2}}{2a+2b+2c} $$

**Properties**

Following "MyMolecule"'s hint, O, circumcenter of the triangle is the midpoint of JJ".(A is not on the line).
The software returns for the distance OJ:
$$OJ=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{-c^{5}+c^{4}\cdot (2\cdot a+2\cdot b)+c^{3}\cdot \left (-2\cdot a^{2}-a\cdot b-2\cdot b^{2}\right )+c^{2}\cdot \left (2\cdot a^{3}-a^{2}\cdot b-a\cdot b^{2}+2\cdot b^{3}\right )+c\cdot \left (-a^{4}+2\cdot a^{3}\cdot b-2\cdot a^{2}\cdot b^{2}+2\cdot a\cdot b^{3}-b^{4}\right )}}{(a+b+c)\cdot \sqrt{(a+b-c)\cdot (a-b+c)\cdot (-a+b+c)}}$$

[image]

Let I be the incenter. A", B' are concyclic and both belong to the circle of center I. More generally, the center of any circle passing through A", B' is located on the line IC.

[image]

Have J,J' ever been named in classical geometry?

Is there a theory about all the points that can be constructed with a straight edge and a compass out of a triangle (intersection of three lines, three circles, etc.)?

Comment: There should also be a similar point $J'$ at the perpendiculars to $A''$ on $AC$, $B''$ on $AB$, and $C''$ on $BC$, with $|AA''| = |BB''| = |CC''| = \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2(a+b+c)}$, right?

Comment: Yes, there is.  I have added the sketch in the original question.

Comment: (+1) , but it would be nice to see a proof that the three lines always intersect in one point and when it is inside or outside the triangle.

Comment: There is an [encyclopedia of triangle centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html) which currently has more than 50000 triangle centers. So chances are this one is already known.

Comment: 1) My remark was about a possible use of Ceva's theorem but it has no place here ! 2) About Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers (ETC), I think it would be interesting to reverse the definition by consider your point as generating its so-called **pedal triangle**. For example, for triangle center X(165), one has a "cousin property" : "If DEF is the pedal triangle of X(165), then |AE| + |AF| = |BF| + |BD| = |CD| + |CE|" (citation of ETC).

Comment: A "triangle center" —in the sense given in the *Encyclopedia* of such— doesn't rely on the order in which you name the vertices. Because $J$ is defined with a specific "orientation" (and $J'$ its reverse), it isn't a "triangle center", and won't appear in the *Encyclopedia*-proper. Instead, $J$ and $J'$ would make a "bicentric pair"; such things are being compiled in a [separate section](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/BicentricPairs.html) of the *ETC*.

Comment: The twin centers $J,J'$ are reminiscent of the two Brocard points $Br_1, Br_2$. $[1]$ Brocard points are concurrency points of lines inclined to sides of $\triangle$ at same angle, in same sense. $J,J'$ are concurrency points of lines perpendicular to sides, at same distance from vertices, in same sense.

Comment: $[2]$ Both Brocard angle $\omega$ and this distance $k$ are unique for any $\triangle$. In fact, the two constants are related as $k=r\cot \omega$, $r=$ inradius. $[3]$ Two Brocard points are equidistant from circumcenter $O$ and the three are concyclic with the Symmedian point. I found $J,J'$ are equidistant and collinear with $O$.

Comment: @Blue following your remark, I have found the bicentric pair of the question in the reference you gave : it is the **"Laemmel points"** P(44) and U(44).

Answer (score 3):

Look at this picture. As said in one of my comments, it is fruitful to consider the issue in a reverse manner : is it possible that an interior point $P$ with *pedal triangle* $A'B'C'$ be such that (red line segments in the figure below) :

$$\underbrace{AB'=BC'=CA'}_{=x} \ \ ?$$

The answer is that, if such an $x$ exists, *necessarily*, its value is :

$$x=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2(a+b+c)}\tag{1}$$

[image]

The proof is easy : applying 3 times the equality of 3 hypotenuses of right triangles (dotted lines), we get

$$\begin{cases}x^2+d_3^2&=&(a-x)^2+d_1^2\\
x^2+d_1^2&=&(b-x)^2+d_2^2\\
x^2+d_2^2&=&(c-x)^2+d_3^2\\\end{cases}$$

Adding these 3 equations, after different cancellations, we get a first degree equation for $x$ whose solution is (1).

Remarks :

1. This proof is as well valid if point $P$ is situated outside triangle $ABC$.
2. One could say that his proof is an analytical equivalent to the proof given by Shaktyai.

The fact that (1) is also a sufficient condition deserves a proof of its own. I will not do it. Let me plainly say that it looks a not-too-difficult task by using the barycentric (or trilinear) coordinates one finds in the [reference](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/BicentricPairs.html)  given by Blue for the so-called **"Laemmel points"** $P(44)$ and $U(44)$.

Comment: Remark : $(d_1 : d_2 : d_3)$ are (proportional to) the **trilinear coordinates** of point P(44) :   $(\sin B + (\cos A \sin C - \sin A) \cos B : \sin C + (\cos B \sin A - \sin B) \cos C  : \sin A + (\cos C \sin B - \sin C) \cos A)$ given in the reference.